# Clang Environment variable for linker path

Tags: macos, linker, clang

I wrote a little Python script to extract the XCode CLTools to a specific directory. (You can find it [here](https://github.com/NiklasRosenstein/xcode-local-cltools) if you want it). Now I just need to get an `activate` script working in order to use the tools from the command-line.

The script updates the `PATH` and `C_INCLUDEPATH`, `CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH`, etc. but now I get linker errors. What environment variables can I use? `C_LINKER_PATH`, `CPLUS_LINKER_PATH`? Or is there another way to make it work?

Since the directory structure is the same as if it was merged into `/`, maybe I can just tell it `~/Clang-5.1` is your new `/` and look from there?

---

```
ABSDIR=$(pwd)/$(dirname ${BASH_SOURCE[0]})
INCLUDE="$ABSDIR/usr/include"

export PATH="$ABSDIR/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin:$PATH"
export C_INCLUDE_PATH="$INCLUDE:$C_INCLUDE_PATH"
export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH="$INCLUDE:$INCLUDE/c++/4.2.2:$CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH"
export OBJC_INCLUDE_PATH="$INCLUDE:$OBJC_INCLUDE_PATH"
export OBJCPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH="$INCLUDE:$INCLUDE/objc:$OBJCPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH"
```

Answer (score 1):

`LIBRARY_PATH` is the right environment variable for this (at least on OSX).